# Directed Join of Digraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

The join of two graphs can be constructed by first forming their sum and then connecting each vertex of the first graph with an edge to each vertex of the second graph.

This construction can easily be generalized to multiple summands as well as digraphs. However, the usual searches haven't given me a reference for the latter. I wonder if you know one?